# Wrong way to use enum?

Tags: c++, enums

I am working on an event system for a game. My original way of going about this was to have a group of listeners stored in a map with a string as the key (event name) and callback for when the event is triggered. This worked fine (In my head, no actual tests done yet), but it didn't take long to find some flaws.

1. **Speed** - I hope to make this a medium sized game. This would mean 100's of "listeners" waiting different events. After an event is called, the search would have to go through every listener string name to find a match. A huge amount of events will be sent and processed as fast as possible to avoid hogging all the time in each frame.
2. **Naming** - "*Shoot_arrow_player*", "*Shoot_arrow_ai*", "*Shoot_arrow_player3*". It's not a very easy system having to remember every event name and could easily have typos and make for annoying debugging.

Then I thought of an odd (In my mind) solution to this. Using enums to categorize and speed up performance.

**Don't worry I'm getting to my question.**

This was the way I setup the enum list:

```
struct Events
{
    enum class Player {
        Start = 1,
        Shoot_arrow,
        Reloading_bow,
        Draw_Bow,
        End
    };
    enum class Enemy {
        Start = (int)Player::End+1,
        Check_for_object,
        Object_spotted,
        Attacking_object,
        End
    };
    enum class Car {
        Start = (int)Enemy::End+1,
        Starting_engine,
        Out_of_gas,
        Car_started,
        End
    };
};
```

With this system, I can use an even faster way of searching for an event if I "categorize" the events. I was thinking of doing something like having a map where the key is the category (start int for each category) and the data is another map, in that map the key is the event (int) and data is the callback. This way I could quickly find the category and then have a lot less to search through. This would be a single function that could return the category:

```
if (event > Event::Enemy)
    return Event::Bear::Start;
else if (event < Event::Enemy)
    return Event::Player::Start;
else
    return Event::Enemy::Start;
```

Then you could search for the event with a much smaller list of possibilities than searching through ever single event. The only downside (That I can think of) is the amount of hard coding I will be doing for each category.

**Now, my question is if this is a correct way to use enums.** I know that the compiler shouldn't throw any errors but I'm wandering if I were to publish this would this be considered bad programming. I'm trying to avoid not being constructive as much as I can but since this will be a critical system I need to make sure it is not a bad thing to do.

Comment: If you're having problems doing hundreds of string matches per second, you're either running this on a 20-year old computer or you've got some very odd compiler options set. A map from `std::string` to some kind of method (lambda?) is the way to organize this. Even better, write an interpreter layer that coverts from a string describing an action to a numerical enum code so your engine doesn't have to worry about the external details.

Comment: @tadman I haven't actually tested it I just assumed it would be slow(er) than ints. If I'm running 60 fps and have 470 events that would be 28,200 searches per frame without any of your methods above. I just figured the more I could cut back the better. I will look into those.

Comment: You'd be surprised how fast a modern CPU can crush through something as routine as a string comparison. I wouldn't be surprised if you could compare in excess of two million strings per second on a single core. If string comparison is a bottleneck, you'll have much bigger problems elsewhere in your engine. In any case, if you have an option to use a binary protocol, strings aren't an issue.

Comment: @tadman Good to know. I will start with my first idea then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you send information *in your event structure* rather than in the enum name.

```
enum Player {/*...*/};
enum Action {Shoot, /*...*/};
enum Weapon {Bow_Arrow, /*...*/};

struct Event
{
  Player receiving_player;
  Action event_action;
  Weapon event_weapon;
};

//...
Event e = {Enemy1, Shoot, Bow_Arrow};
Send_Events(e);
```

This technique can be expanded, such as having a parent event or other events (such as movement).

The concept here is to place the information into a variable rather than the identifier name.

**Edit 1: Player receiving from enemy.**
Let's add another field to the event:

```
struct Event
{
  Player sending_player;
  Player receiving_player;
  Action event_action;
  Weapon event_weapon;
};
```

The event creator would fill in the fields:

```
Event e = {Enemy1, Player2, Shoot, Bow_Arrow);
```

The above event describes the action of `Enemy1` shooting an arrow from a bow at `Player2`.

The next thing is to have an event handler that sends the event to zero or more listeners:

```
struct Event_Listener
{
  virtual void receive_event(const Event& e) = 0;
};

typedef std::vector<Event_Listener *> Event_Listener_Container;
//...
Event_Listener_Container listeners;
Event_Listener_Container::iterator iter;
for (iter = listeners.begin();
     iter != listeners.end();
   ++iter)
{
  (*iter)->receive_event(e);
}
```

Keep in mind, there are various implementations of Listeners, Subscribers and Publishers.  Look up these design patterns.

Comment: Interesting, how  would you have, say the player be notified of the enemy shooting a bow then?

Comment: You could add another field "Player sender;" which would indicate the character who started the action.

Comment: But how would another object be notified of the event? Player1 sends and object, how would player2 get notified Player1 got an object. The only thing I can think of is polling which I'm trying to avoid. That's the only thing I don't get about this.

Comment: `Player1` calls `Player2`'s `receive_event` method.  If the object wants to receive events, it should inherit from `Event_Listener`, as in my latest edit.

Comment: You may want to get the OS involved.  Most multi-tasking OSes have a messaging system.  This allows for one task to send another task a message.  Or another task wake up when a message is received.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO your proposed use of enums smells to high heaven and is dependent on what I would call `coding by coincidence`.  It will be fragile, and once broken really really hard to debug.

For example, suppose I code a reasonable (from the point of view of the language) change to your enums:

```
struct Events
{
    enum class Player {
        Start = 1,
        Shoot_arrow,
        Reloading_bow,
        Draw_Bow,
        End = 0
    };
    enum class Enemy {
        Start = (int)Player::End+1,
        Check_for_object,
        Object_spotted,
        Attacking_object,
        End
    };
    enum class Car {
        Start = (int)Enemy::End+1,
        Starting_engine,
        Out_of_gas,
        Car_started,
        End
    };
};
```

Then your whole strategy is toast.  Your code should not break so easily.

Comment: One problem is that it's pretty much the same deal with strings and say a typo. I guess either I need to come up with a new idea or pick my poison.

Comment: @TrevorPeyton Yeah .. but screwing up one string doesn't screw up all the unrelated strings that you didn't edit.  You should not expect editing one enum type to affect how other enum types are treated.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to plan out these number spaces very deliberately, where 0x10-0x1F are for player actions, 0x20-0x2F for enemy and so on. It's trivial to write a human-readable decoder/encoder for these. Using enums for RPC when they're not assigned specific values is asking for trouble.